# Microsoft purview storage account scan - unable to select all containers

Tags: azure, azure-purview

**Question**: When setting up a `Purview` scan of various containers in an `Azure Storage Account Gen2 (ADLSGen2)`, I am unable to select containers that are at the bottom of selection pane (shown below). The scroll bar is frozen and hence you are not able to select for containers from the bottom half of the containers list. The issue seems to start happening when new option (highlighted in red) was recently introduced - turning this option on or off does not resolve the issue. How can we resolve this issue?

**Ref**: [Scans and ingestion in Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/concept-scans-and-ingestion)
[image]

**UPDATE**:

The above issue is related to `Azure Storage Account` only, the same functionality works fine for `Azure SQL Managed Instance`.

Comment: I think it was a bug I tried similar thing and am able to scroll the containers from ADLSgen2 account from purview scan you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/9ge1km6.png).

Comment: Try to resolve the issue by clearing your browser cache and cookies, or by using a different browser.

Comment: @PratikLad Your suggestion of using a different browser worked (thank you). You may want to convert your comment to a `Response` giving some brief details (including the option of clearing out browser cache) so others can benefit, as well. And, I will mark your response as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As discussed, it in comments posting it as answer to help other community members.**

I tried similar thing and am able to scroll the containers from ADLSgen2 account from purview scan you can see :

[image: here]

**Resolution:**

- Try by clearing your browser cache
- Try by clearing your browsercookies,
- Try using a different browser/ private mode

.

Comment: clearing the cache did not work (but it may work for other users). Changing to different browser worked (thank you). I have posted another relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76469620/1232087) - in case you have time to comment.